# Redirect all sysmail emails to one address for testing purposes

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I want to test sending emails from multiple stored procedures but redirect them all to one email instead of spamming real users.

***Is it possible to configure sysmail to only send email to one address, whatever the specified recipients?***

Comment: Use your own procedure for sending mail which calls sp_send_dbmail, then you can override the recipient(s) however you want

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an old post, but I had the same issue and found a quite easy solution. Simply change the content of the system procedure sp_Send_DBMail.

Disable send mail results in a severity 16 error when code calls the sp_Send_DBMail, so this is not suitable. But adding somewhere at the beginning of the procedure the code:

```
set @recipients = 'someone@mail.com'
```

will do the job.